# How to navigate KendoUI page from code with transition?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I want to navigate from code to some place with slide:right transition for example.

```
app.navigate('#some_page')
```

That code use default page transition. How to change custom transition in code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about:

```
app.navigate(
    '#some_page',
    'slide:right' //or whichever transition you like
);
```

Cheers...

// edit: Changes object to parameters

Comment: No, Kendo app.navigate can receive only page id - not object.

Comment: you're right (at least with the object)...
instead it should be passed as parameters like `app.navigate('view', 'transition');`Sorry, was in the mid of coding observables ^^'

Comment: Just tested it and navigate() does take 2 parameters (URL and TRANSITION). Can be found in the documentation here (at the bottom):
http://docs.kendoui.com/api/mobile/application

Comment: Right! But I think it`s new feature and there are no here on July 30 )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a piece of the documentation that you might be searching for.

http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/application/overview#reverse-transition

Comment: No, it`s navigation with HTML-tags and attributes. I need like as jQueryMobile: $.mobile.changePage('some_page', {transition: 'slide', revese: true}); As I know now - KendoUI can`t do it. And don`t work hack: create an invisible tag <a> and fire click event - in Chrome all ok but on device it`s don`t work